# VISUAL STUDIO, Hay manera de almacenar una porción de código para utilizar varias veces sin repetir todo el codigo?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, revisión-de-código

Buen Día, Tengo varios textbox y todos deben llevar este código en el evento de KeyPress

```
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then

        e.Handled = True
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")

    End If
```

Me preguntaba si hay alguna manera de almacenar el código bajo un alias o alguna otra manera, para luego solo copiar en alias en el evento y se ejecute la acción y así poder mantener el código más limpio.

Disculpen lo básico de la pregunta!

Comment: Si es visual studio supongo que es WEB, yo lo realizaria en jquery, y solo le agregas la función que generes a cada uno de los texboxes.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes varias soluciones al problema que planteas.

La primera solución que veo, si es que todos los `TextBox` hacen la misma acción, es hacer un evento `KeyPress` que este asociado a todos los `TextBox` de tu formulario.

```
Private Sub Evento_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) _
        Handles TextBox1.KeyPress, TextBox2.KeyPress 'Añades todos los TextBox que quieras
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then

        e.Handled = True
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")

    End If
End Sub
```

En el caso de que no tengas que hacer lo mismo en todos los `TextBox`, deberías crear una función o procedimiento que ejecutas en esos eventos, por ejemplo:

```
Private Sub Evento_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Func_KeyPress(e) 'Llamamos la función que hemos creado abajo
End Sub

Private Sub Func_KeyPress(e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then

        e.Handled = True
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")

    End If
End Sub
```